# Get current date from calendar api python

Tags: python, datetime, google-calendar-api

I am trying to make a python program where i can fetch google reminders within a specified period of time, lets say from (2 days before current date) to (2 days after current date). But some how i cant fetch the current date from google calendars API. It gives me a "bad request". I even tried it through saving current date in a variable and then calling it in timeMin and timeMax commands but it didnt work. What could be the best way of fetching current date? any help would be appreciated. Following is my code: -

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
import pickle
import time

scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']

#flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file("client_secret.json", scopes=scopes)
#credentials = flow.run_console()

#pickle.dump(credentials, open("token.pkl", "wb"))
credentials = pickle.load(open("token.pkl", "rb"))
service = build("calendar", "v3" , credentials=credentials)
now = datetime.time.today()
diff = datetime.timedelta(2)

Mintime = now - diff
Maxtime = now + diff
result = service.calendarList().list().execute()
#first = result['items'][0]
second = result['items'][1]
#third = result['items'][2]
#fourth = result['items'][3]
calendar_id = result['items'][1]['id']

result_new = service.events().list(calendarId=calendar_id).execute()
result_newer = result_new['items'][0]['summary']
print(result_newer)
```

Comment: Can you provide the error message, please?

Comment: This is the exact error:-

raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/abjrana%40gmail.com/events?timeMin=2019-10-20&alt=json returned "Bad Request">

Comment: @HuwThomas I solved the error myself only. I was only saving the date in the variable called Mintime however i also had to pass in the time so i concatinated the time string with it manually and now it returns the correct items.